# upload a picture on any photo-sharing service (say. yfrog) using twitter access token and tweet it with some text on twitter

Tags: codeigniter, twitter, twitter-oauth

I am designing an app in php, Codeigniter to be specific and I wanted to know if there is any way I can tweet with picture ... I have seen many third party softwares doing this. So basically my question is can I using twitter oauth access token to upload a picture on any photo sharing service and post it on twitter timeline

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twitpic and yfrog both support "Oauth echo": https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/oauth/oauth-echo

Comment: could you provide an example on how could i use them

Comment: fyi - twitter now have their own API for image upload: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/post/statuses/update_with_media